# NFA simulator error C++

Tags: c++, out-of-memory, runtime-error, nfa

I have one big problem with my NFA simulator.
When I run the code sometimes everything goes nice, but sometimes I get this

```
Process terminated with status -1073741819(0xC0000005)
```

What do I miss out and what to do to get this work fine?

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<map>
using namespace std;
ifstream fin("fisier.txt");
class NFA {
int initiala,finale,stari,tran,cuvinte;
int *f;
multimap <pair <int,int>,char>t;
public:
    void stari_finale();
    void tranzitii();
    void rezolvare();
    };
void NFA::stari_finale()
    {
    fin>>finale;
    f=new int[finale];
    for(int i=1;i<=finale;i++)
        fin>>f[i];
    }

void NFA::tranzitii() 
    {
    fin>>tran;
    for(int i=1;i<=tran;i++)
        {
        int x,y;
        char c2;
        fin>>x>>y>>c2;
        t.insert(make_pair(make_pair(x,y),c2));
        }
    }

void NFA::rezolvare()
{
fin>>stari>>initiala;
fin>>cuvinte;
for(int i=1;i<=cuvinte;i++)
{
    int l;
    fin>>l;
    char *cuv=new char[l+1];
    fin.get();
    fin.getline(cuv,l+1);
    int *c=new int[stari],nr=1;
    c[1]=initiala;
    for(int j=0;j<l;j++)
    {
        int *c1=new int[stari];
        int n=0;
        for(int k=1;k<=nr;k++)
            for(int z=0;z<=stari;z++)
                 if(t.find(make_pair(c[k],z))!=t.end())
                    if(t.find(make_pair(c[k],z))->second==cuv[j])
                        n++,c1[n]=z;
        for(int k=1;k<=n;k++)
            c[k]=c1[k];
        nr=n;
        delete c1;
    }
    for(int j=1;j<=nr;j++)
        {for(int k=1;k<=finale;k++)
            if(c[j]==f[k])
    {
        cout<<"Word "<<cuv<<" is accepted!\n";
        nr=-1;
        break;
    }
    if(nr==-1)
        break;
        }
    if(nr!=-1)
    cout<<"Word "<<cuv<<" isn't accepted!\n";
    delete c;
    delete cuv;
}

}

int main()
{
NFA test;
test.stari_finale();
test.tranzitii();
test.rezolvare();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You make use of `std::multimap`, so why is it that you didn't make use of `std::vector` and `std::string`?  Then none of those calls to `new[]` would be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

One major problem is you are not calling the right delete on your variables.  If you call `new` you need to call `delete`.  If you call `new[]` you need to use `delete[]`.  Mixing `new[]` and `delete` calls will cause undefined behavior which is a symptom of what is happening.

Your calls to delete for `c`, `c1` and `cuv` should all be `delete [] variable_name`

Answer (score 0):

You are writing outside the array here:

```
void NFA::stari_finale()
    {
    fin>>finale;
    f=new int[finale];
    for(int i=1;i<=finale;i++)
        fin>>f[i];
    }
```

`f` has the size `finale`, but `i` will be equal to `finale` in the last iteration.

Use this instead:

```
void NFA::stari_finale()
    {
    fin>>finale;
    f=new int[finale];
    for(int i=0;i<finale;i++)
        fin>>f[i];
    }
```

or, if you really need to use the 1-based indexing:

```
void NFA::stari_finale()
    {
    fin>>finale;
    f=new int[finale + 1];
    for(int i=1;i<=finale;i++)
        fin>>f[i];
    }
```